# в Safari не работакте ИНПУТ дата

Tags: input, safari, кроссбраузерность

Добрый вечер.. такая проблема:

```
<input type="datetime">
```

не работает в сафари вообще...

Вот что мы видим на странице - http://joxi.ru/a2XaW4qU1aoKZA
Во всех остальных браузерах это примерно так - http://joxi.ru/BA0n69LsJVbKOm

Comment: Где вопрос? В Safari никогда и не было поддержки https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: Собственно, в этом и вопрос ... не вижу способа реализации

Comment: Делаем три селекта: день, месяц и год. Да и такой вариант удобней, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Но это то ясно, конечно ) это было самым первым вариантом ... Судя по всему, именно  так и поступают многие, либо выкручиваются другими скриптами

Comment: Ну посмотрите ещё https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/, насколько я помню, он работает в Safari.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял, что сделать штатно невозможно ;) другие варианты я и сам знаю.